# Add a variable with a specific step in a list output

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
pref_network_find = re.findall('(\S+\s+255.255.255\S+)',data)
prefixes = '\n'.join(['ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index permit ' + q for q in pref_network_find])
```

Hi everyone! 
I have this simple code and the output:

```
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index permit 10.185.97.160 255.255.255.224
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index permit 11.185.45.64 255.255.255.240
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index permit 55.110.192.24 255.255.255.248
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index permit 55.110.203.0 255.255.255.0
```

So, what I need is to add a variable to each line of the list automatically assigned a number with a step of ten. It must be a variable binded to number of lines in the list.

Finally, the output must be like this:

```
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index 10 permit 10.185.97.160 255.255.255.224
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index 20 permit 11.185.45.64 255.255.255.240
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index 30 permit 55.110.192.24 255.255.255.248
ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index 40 permit 55.110.203.0 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: This is easy. What's stopping you from doing it? Hint: Use `zip`.

Comment: I think my poor experience stops me )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability: We could simplify this by adding a 0 and start enumerate at 1.

```
l = ['ip ip-prefix VSP_NETWORKS index {}0 permit {}'.format(idx,q) 
    for idx,q in enumerate(pref_network_find,1)]

prefixes = '\n'.join(l)
```